# parseJSON does not work in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I try to do ajax and then back json data in Wordpress.

My Ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : 'html',
            url: "/wp-content/themes/myproject/ajax/otros_alojamientos.php",
            data: { 
                idPost: '<?php echo $ID; ?>'
            },
            success: (function(data) {
                alert(data); // this is my json
                var a = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(a.titulo); // there is not nothing here. Undefined.
            }),
            error: (function(data) {
                console.log('Error alojamientos');
            }),
        });
```

My Json back is:

```
string(50) "{"titulo":"aaatitle","descripcion":"bbbdescription"}"
```

I can not print titulo or descripcion with alert or console.log...

Cheers!

Comment: did you get json value in alert ?

Comment: The json you have posted is not a valid JSON string

Comment: check  [this](https://gist.github.com/zuch/3720842)

Comment: In my php make json_encode, but if i put dataType: json, I get error, Do I need put header or something like that in my php which will be call for ajax?

Comment: `dataType: 'html'` and you're expecting json? ...

Comment: Why don't you create a Associative Array and use `parse_json`? As said @KevinB, change your `dataType`

Comment: I respond with json from php

Answer (score 1):

change your datatype param

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        url: "/wp-content/themes/myproject/ajax/otros_alojamientos.php",
        data: { 
            idPost: '<?php echo $ID; ?>'
        },
        success: (function(data) {
            alert(data.titulo); // data is parsed as Json by jQuery
        }),
        error: (function(data) {
            console.log('Error alojamientos');
        }),
    });
```

you should check your error callback function params also (it doesn't expect data as 1st param)

Comment: @davidcm86 Then your json is invalid. Changing to HTML just makes it work because an invalid json string is still considered a valid html string. Please read the actual error message that gets passed to you in the error callback.

Comment: Your json is invalid, as wrote Kevin B. Your json string looks like a php var_dump display, but {"titulo":"aaatitle","descripcion":"bbbdescription"} (without the String() " " part) is a valid json

Answer (score 0):

Well the response you are getting that is neither a valid `json` or valid `html`. So either you remove the dataType and then you have to parse it or just add `dataType:"json"` but in your case that is not a valid `json`.

So i would like to tell you that you should use `dataType:"text"` and then you can parse it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'text',
    url: "/wp-content/themes/myproject/ajax/otros_alojamientos.php",
    data: { 
        idPost: '<?php echo $ID; ?>'
    },
    success: (function(data) {
        var json = data.split(' ')[1]; // gets you the json string
        var validJson = $.parseJSON(json); // parses as valid json
        alert(validJson.titulo);
    }),
    error: (function(data) {
        console.log('Error alojamientos');
    }),
});
```

Comment: If I put this code, I never see the alert, I do not why...and I do not recive any error, everything in success it is OK, but the code does not continue.